# How to draw linear inequalities in LaTeX

Tags: pgfplots, plot

I want to draw the following inequalities in LaTeX.

[image]
This set of inequalities define a region. I want to plot this set of inequalities. How can I do this?

I want to achieve something like this.

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you understand as “plot this inequalities”? Could you upload an image of what you are trying to achieve? May be it's not possible with those equations by themselves but with some hand-calculated points you can draw/fill regions… but as I said, I'm not sure of what you really want to achieve.

Comment: Check the answer .

Comment: Then TikZ is an easy way. Just draw those points and connect them with lines. You can see basic examples in the documentation.